# Kafka Mysql Connector plugin.path configuration

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, debezium

I'm trying out to connect `mysql` with `kafka`.  I've downloaded `debezium-debezium-connector-mysql`

[image]

This is my `connect-standalone.properties` :

```
# These are defaults. This file just demonstrates how to override some settings.
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
# Flush much faster than normal, which is useful for testing/debugging
offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

# Set to a list of filesystem paths separated by commas (,) to enable class loading isolation for plugins
# (connectors, converters, transformations). The list should consist of top level directories that include 
# any combination of: 
# a) directories immediately containing jars with plugins and their dependencies
# b) uber-jars with plugins and their dependencies
# c) directories immediately containing the package directory structure of classes of plugins and their dependencies
# Note: symlinks will be followed to discover dependencies or plugins.
# Examples: 
# plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,
plugin.path=/home/ec2-user/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-debezium-connector-mysql/lib
```

My `test.config` :

```
{
  "name": "mysql-source-demo-customers",
  "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
      "database.hostname": "localhost",
      "database.port": "3306",
      "database.user": "root",
      "database.password": "dsm1234",
      "database.server.id": "42",
      "database.server.name": "asgard",
      "table.whitelist": "demo.customers",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092",
      "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.demo" ,
      "include.schema.changes": "true",
      "transforms": "unwrap,InsertTopic,InsertSourceDetails",
      "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.UnwrapFromEnvelope",
      "transforms.InsertTopic.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
      "transforms.InsertTopic.topic.field":"messagetopic",
      "transforms.InsertSourceDetails.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value",
      "transforms.InsertSourceDetails.static.field":"messagesource",
      "transforms.InsertSourceDetails.static.value":"Debezium CDC from MySQL on asgard"
  }
}
```

When I run `bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties test.config`,

I get an error :

> [2019-11-19 09:10:45,146] INFO Scanning for plugin classes. This might take a moment ... (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:78)
>   [2019-11-19 09:10:45,170] INFO Loading plugin from: /home/ec2-user/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-debezium-connector-mysql/lib/mysql-binlog-connector-java-0.19.1.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:222)
>   [2019-11-19 09:10:45,291] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/home/ec2-user/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-debezium-connector-mysql/lib/mysql-binlog-connector-java-0.19.1.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:245)
>   [2019-11-19 09:10:45,292] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.AllConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:174)
>   [2019-11-19 09:10:45,292] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.PrincipalConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:174)
>   [2019-11-19 09:10:45,292] INFO Added plugin 'org.apache.kafka.connect.connector.policy.NoneConnectorClientConfigOverridePolicy' (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:174)
>   [2019-11-19 09:10:45,293] INFO Loading plugin from: /home/ec2-user/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-debezium-connector-mysql/lib/debezium-connector-mysql-0.10.0.Final.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:222)
>   [2019-11-19 09:10:45,324] ERROR Stopping due to error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:130)
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/util/IoUtil
>           at io.debezium.connector.mysql.Module.(Module.java:19)
>           at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector.version(MySqlConnector.java:47)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:350)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.versionFor(DelegatingClassLoader.java:355)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.getPluginDesc(DelegatingClassLoader.java:331)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanPluginPath(DelegatingClassLoader.java:311)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.scanUrlsAndAddPlugins(DelegatingClassLoader.java:244)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.registerPlugin(DelegatingClassLoader.java:236)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initPluginLoader(DelegatingClassLoader.java:205)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader.initLoaders(DelegatingClassLoader.java:182)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.(Plugins.java:61)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone.main(ConnectStandalone.java:79)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.debezium.util.IoUtil
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
>           at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:104)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
>           ... 12 more

By looking at the log, `io/debezium/util/IoUtil` seems like a problem.
 (I googled and stackoverflowed about the plugin path. I found a similar question in Stackoverflow and followed it, but still not working. )

What am I missing?

Comment: How about `plugin.path=/usr/local/share/java,/usr/local/share/kafka/plugins,/opt/connectors,/home/ec2-user/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-debezium-connector-mysql/lib` ?

Comment: You should just need `/home/ec2-user/share/confluent-hub-components`, not so deep in the filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used the Confluent Hub client to install the connector, you shouldn't need to edit the plugin path. It's recursively scanned, so just `/home/ec2-user/share/confluent-hub-components` should work.

Sidenote: I'd suggest storing plugins somewhere other than the ec2-user home folder, as such long running processes typically run as their own, limited, user account